# C# Add-in: How do you access runtime instances of objects while debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, runtime, add-in, envdte

I am developing an add in for C# that would only be used during debugging. Once instantiated, my add in needs to find all instances of a specific class or interface to display a graph about the data found.

How exactly can I find or access these objects in my extension?  I have access to the DTE2 application object in my extension, but I'm not sure how to search the actual code being debugged by VS.  I'm thinking I might somehow be able to use Reflection, but I'm not sure where to look.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've implemented a plugin that searches through dlls in a given directory and finds classes that implement a particular interface.  Below is the class I used to do this:

```
public class PlugInFactory<T>
{
    public T CreatePlugin(string path)
    {
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.dll"))
        {
            foreach (Type assemblyType in Assembly.LoadFrom(file).GetTypes())
            {
                Type interfaceType = assemblyType.GetInterface(typeof(T).FullName);

                if (interfaceType != null)
                {
                    return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyType);
                }
            }
        }

        return default(T);
    }
}
```

All you have to do is initialize this class with something like this:

```
PluginLoader loader = new PlugInFactory<InterfaceToSearchFor>();
InterfaceToSearchFor instanceOfInterface = loader.CreatePlugin(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
```

Comment: This is useful, but I need the actual instances of the classes that are found. Not just which classes implement an interface.  Still might use this somehow if @JaredPar is correct and my request is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

This type of operation isn't really possible from a Visual Studio plugin.  The object alive when debugging live in the debugee process while your add-in is running in the Visual Studio process.  It's not possible to access arbitrary objects across process boundaries in .Net.